# Python Request.Post to API not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a simple POST to an api.

```
import requests
url ="http://someapi/v1/auth"
payload = {'username': '', 'password': ''}
s1 = requests.post(url, headers={"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, data=json.dumps(payload))  
print s1.status_code
```

I keep getting status code 401.

Same steps Works fine in POSTMAN.

[image]

[image]

Any Ideas/pointers ?

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. Have you the right credentials?

Comment: I do. Post works from POSTMAN but fails from Python.

Comment: Use *json.dumps* if your content type is "application/json"

Comment: Please fix: freehand circle is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post data in raw format.

```
payload = "username=;password=;"

s1 = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers={"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    data=payload)
```

**FWIW,** you can click on *Code* below the *Save* button on the top right corner of Postman to view code in a couple of languages for your request.

Comment: I keep getting "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".   I am not sure why Python is blocking it. I will research more. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @ProgSky, Have you tried with the payload = "username=&password="?

Comment: Yeah. I did . I continue to get 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials .

Comment: I might have to use "HttpNtlmAuth" to authenticate with current user.

Comment: using requests_ntlm worked for me. I have posted my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

It will only works if the API accepts also JSON body.
Otherwise you can use the @Oluwafemi Sule's answer.

```
import requests
url ="http://someapi/v1/auth"
payload = {'username': '', 'password': ''}
s1 = requests.post(url, headers={"content-type":"application/json"}, data=json.dumps(payload))  
print s1.status_code
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
payload = "username=;password=;"
s= requests.post(
        "http://someapi/v1/auth", 
        headers={"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        data = payload, 
        auth=HttpNtlmAuth('',''))
print s.status_code
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for your post.